# How to print specified in sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This is my below code for printing numbers in reverse and go on decrementing it. I am able to print but it should start from bottom to top. Basically, i need the below output.

```
5 4 3 2 1 
4 3 2 1 
3 2 1
2 1
1
```

I have written the below query but I am unable to put it in the above format. The below code is in SQL. Any help would be appreciated.

```
DECLARE @X INT,@STRING VARCHAR (100)
SET @STRING = ''
SET @X = 1

WHILE @X<6
    BEGIN
        SET @STRING = @STRING +' '+ CAST (@X AS VARCHAR (100))
        PRINT REVERSE(@STRING)

        SET @X +=1
    END
```

The above query is giving me the below output:

```
1 
2 1 
3 2 1 
4 3 2 1 
5 4 3 2 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use a recursive CTE to get the data you need, then use a cursor to handle the print statements (if you can't use a recordset). The query would be something like this:

```
with numbers(n, s) AS (
    SELECT 1, convert(varchar(max), 1)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT n+1, convert(varchar(max), n+1) + ' ' + s 
    FROM numbers
    WHERE n < 5
)
SELECT s FROM numbers ORDER BY n DESC
```

giving you this:

```
s
5 4 3 2 1
4 3 2 1
3 2 1
2 1
1
```

Again, if you need to print the values (rather than getting as a recordset), you can use a cursor to loop over the results.

Comment: I would like to see the teacher's  face when he gets recursive CTE instead of procedural loop :)

Comment: Appreciate your effort Zack. But can we use any conditional statement to do this like while loop?

Comment: The while loop would be over the cursor.

Answer (score 1):

You could use helper variable:

```
DECLARE @X INT = 1
       ,@STRING VARCHAR (1000) = ''
       ,@res VARCHAR(1000) = '';

WHILE @X<6
BEGIN
    SET @STRING = CAST (@X AS VARCHAR (100)) + ' ' + @STRING;
    SET @res = @STRING + CHAR(10) + @res;
    SET @X +=1;
END

PRINT @res;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1837a6e2905267030c6a940fecfb133c)**

Output:

```
5 4 3 2 1
4 3 2 1 
3 2 1 
2 1
1
```

Comment: Thnx Lukasz. Really appreciate. But can you provide more information on what is helper variable? what it is?

Comment: @TushalSingh So instead of immediately PRINT result I add it to helper variable `SET @res = @STRING + CHAR(10) + @res;` and then print at once

Answer (score -1):

```
DECLARE @X INT,@STRING VARCHAR (100)
SET @STRING = ''
SET @X = 1

WHILE @X<6
BEGIN
    SET @STRING = CAST (@X AS VARCHAR (100)) + ' ' + @STRING
    PRINT REVERSE(@STRING)

    SET @X +=1
END
```

Comment: This still only gives the string as 1; 2, 1; 3, 2, 1; etc.

Comment: Thanx for the help Daniel. But still it is not giving me the output.